# Learning curve of JAX-RS client sided Frameworks

Tags: rest, jersey, cxf, restlet, resteasy

Can some people exchange their experiences about the learning curve of frameworks like Apache CXF, Restlet, Resteasy, Jersey and their documentation/support? Especially when it is about invoking a restful service. Edit: So, not just invoking, also stuff like content negotiation, caching...

Comment: i am working on apache cxf --it has good documentation.But needs more examples.
I am working on cxf with jaxws and cxf with jax-rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a delight for me working with the RI - Jersey. It's pretty straightforward and well documented. The wiki @ https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/Main has a lot of helpful resources. You can get good support on it here as well.